# Why is URI Online always giving me “Presentation Error”

Tags: c, printf

Most of the time I use C++ to deal with URI Online problems, but this time I need to use C.
I have solved the computational part, but URI keeps giving me the classical “Presentation error problem”.
I know I have to break the line at the end, but neither `\n` or `\r\n` nor anything else seems to fix this problem.
Here's my code:

```
int main () {

    double R,PI,a;
    PI = 3.14159;
    scanf("%lf", &R);
    a = PI * (pow(R,2));
    printf ("A=%0.4f", a, "\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `printf ("A=%0.4f", a, "\n");` --> `printf ("A=%0.4f\n", a);`

Comment: Also, please do not use `pow` for squaring. `R*R` is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood how `printf` works. It does not concatenate all the stuff you throw into it like you're used to from `std::cout << … << …;` but instead mostly prints the first argument, the format string. The latter arguments only come into play when the format string requests them, as you do with the `%0.4f` for the second argument. However, the third is unused. You could fix it like this:

```
printf("A=%0.4f%s", a, "\n");
```

Or, more idiomatically, like this:

```
printf("A=%0.4f\n", a);
```

By the way, at least my gcc warns me:

> main.c: In function ‘main’:
>   main.c:…: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
>     printf ("A=%0.4f", a, "\n");